# Server-sent event does not work with jersey SSE

Tags: java, jersey, servlet-3.0, server-sent-events, jersey-2.0

I am trying to use JavaScript SSE from Jersey. I have Following code in my resource. I am hosting on Java7 and Tomcat 7. I dont get any error. But I don't see data either on page.

I call `/broadcast` to post data. It does show message. But nothing comes on client. In Firefox, I do see `/broadcast` event fired multiple times.

This is reference I used.
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html

```
    package net.jigarshah.dse.tracker;

    import javax.inject.Singleton;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEvent;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseBroadcaster;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature;


@Singleton
@Path("broadcast")
public class SSEResource {
    private SseBroadcaster broadcaster = new SseBroadcaster();

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)    
    public String broadcastMessage(String message) {
        OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
        message = message + "\n\n";
        OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.name("message")
            .mediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .data(String.class, message)
            .build();

        broadcaster.broadcast(event);
        System.out.println("broadcasting listen [" +message+ "]");

        return "Message was '" + message + "' broadcast.";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput listenToBroadcast() {
        System.out.println("will listen");
        final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
        this.broadcaster.add(eventOutput);
        return eventOutput;
    }
}
```

My Index.html code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "webapi/broadcast";
//var url="http://localhost:8080/trackapp/webapi/broadcast/listen";
var source=new EventSource(url);
source.onerror=function(event)
{
console.log("error [" + source.readyState + "]");
};

source.onopen = function(event){
    console.log("eventsource opened!");
    };

source.onmessage=function(event)
  {
    console.log(event.data);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try using curl on the command line? Sometimes browsers cache responses.

Comment: @Salil can you please provide example on how to do this subscription using curl ?

Comment: It's a command line utility program, proided by default on most Unix/Linux (including Mac OS X). http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/curl-examples/

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and solved it by not setting the name of the event (i don't know why but this seems to be the solution)... here is the code

```
OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();

//WARNING: IF I SET THE NAME OF THE EVENT IT DOES NOT WORK
//eventBuilder.name("message"); 

eventBuilder.mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
eventBuilder.data(EventData.class, data);
OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
```

Comment: On the client side, when no named event is sent, it triggers the `eventSource.onmessage` handler.  When one is set, you should be setting `eventSource.addEventListener('eventnamehere', function(ev){}`

Answer (score 5):

The [OutboundEvent.Builder.name](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/OutboundEvent.Builder.html#name(java.lang.String)) method sets the value of the SSE event field. Therefore, it is not treated as a message and cannot be listened using the .onmessage handler. The solution is simply using the `addEventListener` method to register the listener method.

This code should work with the Jersey sample above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "webapi/broadcast";
    var source=new EventSource(url);
    source.addEventListener(
        "message",
        function(event){
            console.log(event.data);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>"; },
        false);
</script>
```

I found this article to be useful to understand how the SSE works in the browser side: http://www.sitepoint.com/server-sent-events/.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example which might be helpful to you: http://en.kodcu.com/2013/11/jaxrs-2-html-5-server-sent-events-on-glassfish-4/

And you may also refer to this page to see if your browser supports EventSource API http://www.eventsourcehq.com/browser-support

Comment: first link is dead, second one returns 503

Answer (score 1):

I have to do the following to make it work with tomcat 7.0.69 and java 1.8, and jersey 2.22.2 Just sharing it if it comes to any use of any body.

1. Add the following dependency in your Pom file :

   ```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.2</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.2</version>
     </dependency>
   <!-- If you use json -->
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.2</version>
     </dependency>
   <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
         <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
         <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.2</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.2</version>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. Needs to be servlet 3 so Heading of the web.xml should be like this :


   `< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? >
       < web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0" >`
3. Jersey Servlet Container should be async-supported, so add it in the jersey servlet in the web.xml :

< async-supported>true< /async-supported >

5. If you use any filter make sure it also async-supported :

   < async-supported>true< /async-supported>